# Is there an alternative to using rbash to restrict a user on my system?

Tags: bash, shell-script, account-restrictions, restricted-shell

Basically at the moment I am using `rbash` to stop a user from leaving his directory on my system. The problem with this is, there is a script in my bin which he needs to be able to run from a script in his bin (it is because I am using screen).

The issue with this is that he gets the permission denied error because he can not CD out of his directory like the script that is in his bin requires him to do.

I thought that the simple answer would to very simply make root the owner of the script by following the instructions in this post but still I got the error.

Does anyone know of either an alternative to using rbash to restrict users which would allow me to let the user run this script, or does someone know of a way that will let him ruhn this script?

Thanks

Comment: You could set up a sym-link to the file.

Comment: I think I may me wrong about syslinks, If so a hardlink will work.

Comment: @richard I made a hardlink but it does not run the same as it does when run it in my own account. Do you have any idea why this would be?

Comment: Has it got configuration files in same directory? In the name the same?

Comment: Do you have to restrict him? You can use permissions on the rest of the system to prevent access. Though this is a bit more tricky.

Comment: There is also chroot, there are tools to help set-up a chroot. A chroot sets up a sub system, with a new root. So can restrict to a subdirectory tree, but all resources have to be in this tree. Can not even read from `/bin`, the tool will help set this up.

Answer (score 2):

If you're jailing the user, you should probably just give him a copy of the script.  If you set him up with a chrooted account, he wouldn't see anything outside of his home directory.

Comment: I would have done this but the scrip needs to CD into another HDD and run a server starting script in there. Do you have any other solutions? Thanks